# Qt 5.7 stacked bar chart automatically rescale y-axis on data update

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtcharts

I have adapted the Qt [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-stackedbarchart-example.html)  to add another set of data to the existing, on the push of a button.  The data is added, (stacked on top), and there is a neat resizing animation but then the data is cut off at the top of the chart. How can I automatically rescale the y-axis to show the next data?

```
QBarSet *set = new QBarSet("NewSet");
*set << 12 << 11 << 13 << 12 << 11 << 13;
series->append( set );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chart->removeSeries(series);
chart->addSeries( series );
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->setAxisX(axis, series);
```

adapted from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-stackedbarchartdrilldown-drilldownchart-cpp.html